# Qualcomm SDK customization?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, qcar-sdk

I am trying to edit multi targets and image targets sample app of qualcomm sdk so that instead of using openGL , I can only overlay UIKit contents such as buttons text etc just for a simple demo. But I am unable to do so till now.

Please guide me where to make any changes or how to go about it?

I have also referred to the forums and tried to examples but they all are using openGL which i want to get rid of.

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main duty of the QCAR is to give you a 4x4 matrix called `ModelView` matrix with which you can superimpose your graphics. This is an OpenGL matrix and I don't think that you would be able to use that matrix in UIKIT.

If you only want to overlay some UIs stuff when a target is detected then you don't need that matrix. But the UIs will be on the screen in 2D (not on the target image in 3D scene) and tha't not AR at all.

Another option is to incorporate a rendering engine with QCAR to avoid using pure OpenGL ES APIs. For iPhone I think `OpenFramework` should do the business.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. I figured out how to use it with the help of who is one of the moderators on qualcomm's forum. I had to completely remove the opengl matrix and add a custom UIClass which was to be called right after detection.